# Opencart module quanity bespoke modification issue

Tags: php, opencart

I had a mod made for opencart enabling me to allow my local customers add additional item to their order 24 hours before local delivery.

Basically my shop is made up of one-off items and the quantity is generally 1

The modification that was made works fine but..

Say the conditions are: Iv'e added 3 items to my cart and processed my order for local delivery.

Then.. I go to add more to my order.

The form below on my pastebin allows me to add additional items to the order but when it does it re-checks the other items on the order and because they are technically out of stock they get removed from the amend order page.

I hope ive made sense and someone wants to help. Thanks!

CODE: http://pastebin.com/CsHts0FR

Comment: Do not post the code to pastebin but include it here - directly in the question. Also do not post here the whole file (unless less then few dozens of lines) but post only the most important part of the code that is relevant to the problem being asked here.

Comment: Also the code at pastebin is only the template while we need the controller code - especially the part that does the check for the item quantity and remove them if they are out of stock. The code at pastebin is very chaotically line-wrapped thus making it hard to read (even if it was relevant to the problem **which is not the case**).

Comment: sorry about my in-experience. I have found the snippet in the controller file, and put it in patebin again because its still a little bit big. http://pastebin.com/qPr3MArp